# How do I inherit keys in parent class dictionary in child classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to write Cypress UI test automation in which I am capturing UI elements on each webpage in its own class. I have two classes corresponding to different webpages:

```
class WebPage1 {
    elements = {
        e1: () => console.log('return e1'), //this will be something like "cy.get('...')" in cypress
        e2: () => console.log('return e2'),
        e3: () => console.log('return e3')
    }
}

class WebPage2 {
    elements = {
        e1: () => console.log('return e1'),
        e2: () => console.log('return e2'),
        e4: () => console.log('return e4')
    }
}
```

Note that both these classes have the same keys `e1` and `e2` (since both the webpages contain same elements) in their `elements` dictionary.
Also these classes have somewhat specialization of same concept. So I was thinking if I can have a parent class which will contain `e1` and `e2` keys and `WebPage1` and `WebPage2` will inherit these keys. But how can I inherit just some keys of a parent class' dictionary? Is it possible? I tried this:

```
class ParentPage {
    e1() {
        console.log('return e1') //this will be something like "return cy.get('...')" in cypress
    }

    e2() {
        console.log('return e2')
    }
}

class WebPage1 extends ParentPage {
    elements = {
        e1: () => this.e1,
        e2: () => this.e2,
        e3: () => console.log('return e3')
    }
}

class WebPage2 extends ParentPage  {
    elements = {
        e1: () => this.e1,
        e2: () => this.e2,
        e4: () => console.log('return e4')
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it or there is any other better way?

Comment: Try using keyword `get` in ParentPage class: `get e1() { console.log('return e1') }`

Comment: Your example code returns functions instead of calling them, which is not what you mean

Comment: It doesn't really feel like classes are what you need here.  Maybe you just want to keep an object of common elements around and copy or spread from that like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAVgvW)?  I guess it depends on your use case as to whether anything is "better" than (a corrected version of) what you have.

Comment: @jcalz Do you mean `new WebPage2().elements.e1` returns function? I call these functions as `this.elements.e1().click()` further in other methods (not shown in the code as its not relevant to doubt) of `WebPageX`. It works. (Notice `e1()`.)

Comment: When you say "it works" you mean code you're not showing here.  Your example code does not work: [observe](https://tsplay.dev/mpDAgm).  Please let me know if you still disagree.

Comment: Sorry if it sounded like it was TS. This is indeed JS. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/ptwjh946/6/) is something how I am calling `e1`.  It might be breaking because, I didnt realise that I have to include double `()()`. Before adding `ParentClass`, single `()` used to work.

Comment: @jcalz tbh I am not seasoned JS developer and never worked in JS. But worked a lot in Python, Java and some other languages. So pardon me for some more naive doubts. **Q1.** `...commonElements` in TS includes those elements inside dictionary? **Q2.** Is that `constructor()` thing in rightside panel (of typescriptlang.org link you shared) an JS equivalent `...commonElements` in TS

Comment: There's no difference between JS and TS when it comes to how you've refactored your example.  In JS and TS, your refactored version does not behave the same as your original example.  You shouldn't have to write `()()` anywhere.  The problem is that your refactored example *returns* a function instead of *calling* it.  It should be like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3zEyN) instead.  Or something else that behaves the same; refactoring should not change behavior.  Does this make sense? I'm  kind of losing steam explaining this, so I hope you get it soon.

Comment: A1: [object spread operator](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals). A2: TS is mostly just JS with an erasable static type system. If you erase types, TS should be JS for some version of JS: [this](//tsplay.dev/wXklQW) shows that the emitted JS targeting ESNext+[class fields](//github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) is essentially identical to the TS. If your target JS runtime does not support class fields or object spread, then `constructor()` and `Object.assign()` respectively can be used to get equivalent functionality.